# Display quantity with "if conditions"

Tags: products, store-view, quantity, qty

I use this to display the quantity of my products.

```
<div class="availability-qty">
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Qty Available:') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= (int) Mage:: getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

It works perfectly but, I want to display it only "if" it's a specific store.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() == 5):?>
    <div class="availability-qty">
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Qty Available:') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= (int) Mage:: getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: As a point of note it is always better to get store id from some setting you can easily change and not hardcode it.